# gridview column delete

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Is there any other way to delete gridview column except using index..
I am using gridview with multiple checkbox.
I want to delete all those column whose checkboxes are checked..
I am retriving checkboxes as..

```
protected void ButtonApprove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringCollection sc = new StringCollection();
    string id = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)//loop the GridView Rows
    {
        //find the CheckBox
        CheckBox cb = 
           (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBox1");
        if (cb != null)
        {
            if (cb.Checked)
            {
                // get the id of the field to be deleted
                id = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
                // add the id to be deleted in the StringCollection
                sc.Add(id); 
            }
        }
    }
    UpdateRecords(sc);
}
```

Comment: More information please what you are doing and what you exactly need

Comment: So you want to delete all the selected records right

Comment: exactly..I want to delete all checked ones and add them to another gridview

Comment: Even though you are writing this code from the blog why you are unable to do and please mark the previous question marked as answer that are solved

Comment: Why you want to delete and why you are going to add to another grid view

Comment: as per the requirement..as I checked the checkbox the role changes and that checkbox column should have to go to the gridview of that particular value..

Comment: So your requirement is to move the selected gridview to another by removing from the first one

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the [Link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Select-and-delete-multiple-rows-in-ASP.Net-Gridview-control.aspx) for deleting multiple items

Check this to move the selected to another gridivew [Move](http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.com/2009/04/how-to-move-selected-record-from-one.html)